# Different arrangement of array values

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to create an array of addresses based on a reversegeocode function that I will attach below that works. However every time I enter latitudes and longitudes from an array of values and then append it to my address era the order of the era always gets messed up. Here is my code:

```
func getAddressFromLatLon(pdblLatitude: Double, withLongitude pdblLongitude: Double){
    var center : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    let lat: Double = pdblLatitude
    //21.228124
    let lon: Double = pdblLongitude
    //72.833770
    let ceo: CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
    center.latitude = lat
    center.longitude = lon

    let loc: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude:center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude)


    ceo.reverseGeocodeLocation(loc, completionHandler:
        {(placemarks, error) in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print("reverse geodcode fail: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
            let pm = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]

            if pm.count > 0 {
                let pm = placemarks![0]
                print(pm.country)
                print(pm.locality)
                print(pm.subLocality)
                print(pm.thoroughfare)
                print(pm.postalCode)
                print(pm.subThoroughfare)

                if pm.subThoroughfare != nil {
                    addressString = addressString + pm.subThoroughfare! + " "
                }
                if pm.thoroughfare != nil {
                    addressString = addressString + pm.thoroughfare! + ", "
                }
                if pm.locality != nil {
                    addressString = addressString + pm.locality! + ", "
                }
                if pm.administrativeArea != nil {
                    addressString = addressString + pm.administrativeArea! + " "
                }
                if pm.postalCode != nil {
                    addressString = addressString + pm.postalCode! + " "
                }
                print (addressString)
                addressStrings.append(addressString)
                addressString = ""
            }
    })
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    print(#function)
}


@IBAction func onSearh(_ sender: Any) {
    for i in 0 ..< ((stores!.count)-1)  {
        print (latitudes[i])
        print (longitudes[i])
        getAddressFromLatLon(pdblLatitude: latitudes[i], withLongitude: longitudes[i])
    }
```

I was wondering if you can just enter this in your projects or figure out why the function is deterministic by giving me different outputs for the same input?

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. I have tested your `getAddressFromLatLon` function, and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse geocoding is an asynchronous function, since it is a network request and hence your function calls might not return in the same order as they were called.

If you need them in the exact same order as they were called, you could run the `getAddressFromLatLon` function in a serial queue. This will ensure the order of your results, but it will have performance disadvantages, since your network requests cannot run concurrently in this case.

If I were you, I would change my data structure into a struct, from which I can access elements with an identifier other than the index (for example, a dictionary with an identifier as the key and the address as the value). In this case you could still run your reverse geocoding function concurrently.